# django-haystack. How can I filter `sqs.filter(id__in=qs_pk)` if I have `qs_pk` list with more than 1024 elements?

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

Here is my code:

```
qs_pk = Vacancy.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True)
sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Vacancy)
sqs = sqs.filter(id__in=qs_pk)
```

when I try to use `sqs.count()` method I get an exception:

> elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'Failed to parse query [id:("281134" OR "281135" OR "272222" OR "287848" OR "190255" OR "266921" OR "235700" OR "235683" OR "281138" OR "281144" OR "186683" OR "281145" OR "281147" OR "244712" ................

but if I restrict `qs_pk = qs_pk[:1024]` then it's all right.

Answer (score 0):

I've found something in `elasticsearch` logs:

`Caused by: org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery$TooManyClauses: maxClauseCount is set to 1024`

Perhaps that need to edit some value of `elasticsearch.yml`